# TypeError: xxx is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var Fishbowl = require('node-fishbowl');

var fb = new Fishbowl.Fishbowl({
    host: 'X.X.X.X',
    IADescription: 'Reporting Dashboard',
    IAID: 2286,
    IANAME: 'node-dashboard',
    password: 'X',
    port: '28192',
    username: 'X',
    bunyanLevel: 'debug'
});
```

The above code returns "TypeError: Fishbowl.Fishbowl is not a constructor".  I've tried just about everything I can think of to get around this but I have been unsuccessful.

Running Node.js v8.2.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `var Fishbowl = require('node-fishbowl').default;`

Comment: It returns the same error.  Fishbowl.Fishbowl is not a constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an error in their documentation, they now export Fishbowl as `default`.

Try this:

```
var Fishbowl = require('node-fishbowl');

var fb = new Fishbowl({
    host: 'X.X.X.X',
    IADescription: 'Reporting Dashboard',
    IAID: 2286,
    IANAME: 'node-dashboard',
    password: 'X',
    port: '28192',
    username: 'X',
    bunyanLevel: 'debug'
});
```

Look at the [source](https://github.com/gpit2286/node-fishbowl/blob/master/src/fishbowl.ts) it changed in [cc3a400](https://github.com/gpit2286/node-fishbowl/commit/cc3a400b672b3ab87709d4c72514ac35b56c1a86#diff-7b76139115b2f2acc100046e45642d70).