# TypeError: Name.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nedb

I am writing a unit test for a service class called `TaskService`. The  unit test injects a TaskService instance, whose constructor goes ahead to create a DB connection to NeDB. (i know I should mock this connection but I need to get the unit test working before I can optimise it).

*task.service.ts*

```typescript
import {Injectable, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {Task} from "./task.model";
import Datastore from 'nedb';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService implements OnDestroy {
  private tasks: any;

  constructor(private _logger: Logger) {
    this._logger.log("Task Service Constructor");

    this.tasks = new Datastore({filename: 'db/tasks.json'});


  }
```

**Error Message**

```html
 TypeError: nedb_1.default is not a constructor
            at new TaskService I:/Projects/taskmelater/src/app/tasks/shared/task.service.ts:22:18)
            at _createClass I:/Projects/taskmelater/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:9529:1)
            at _createProviderInstance$1 I:/Projects/taskmelater/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:9503:1)
            at resolveNgModuleDep I:/Projects/taskmelater/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:9488:1)
            at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get I:/Projects/taskmelater/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:10562:1)
            at TestBed.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js.TestBed.get I:/Projects/taskmelater/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:819:1)
            at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js.TestBed.get I:/Projects/taskmelater/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:656:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> I:/Projects/taskmelater/src/app/tasks/shared/task.service.spec.ts:20:24)
            at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke I:/Projects/taskmelater/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke I:/Projects/taskmelater/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
```

The test runner is complaining about the `this.tasks = new Datastore({filename: 'db/tasks.json'});` line.

Here is the index.js file for the NeDB package.

**index.js**

```html
var Datastore = require('./lib/datastore');

module.exports = Datastore;
```

I read through a ton of similar questions but they are about a custom class that causes this error. In my case I am trying to use a non Typescript npm package in my Angular 4 application. the import statements for non typescript packages are always tricky to get right.

**app.module.ts**

```html
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StarterComponent,
    StarterHeaderComponent,
    StarterLeftSideComponent,
    StarterContentComponent,
    StarterFooterComponent,
    StarterControlSidebarComponent,
    TasksComponent,
    TaskComponent,
    TaskFormComponent,
TaskService
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AdminModule,
    AgGridModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule

  ],
  providers: [TaskService, Logger],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, TaskService, Logger]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### Questions consulted:

[TypeError: xxx is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165107/typeerror-xxx-is-not-a-constructor)

*I cannot apply the solution in this question because NeDB is an NPM package, not my own class:*
[Error: *.default is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652423/error-default-is-not-a-constructor)

Comment: thanks for the markdown. thought i should post it anyway because it is resolved...

Answer (score -2):

I finished typing the question and then stumbled across this github issue:
https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/issues/681

One comment states the following:

> This works:
>
> import Alt from 'alt/lib'
>
> var alt = new Alt();
>
> module.exports = alt;

In my case, rather than importing NeDB using `import  Datastore from 'nedb'`, I removed the import and instead added the following to my constructor:
  `var Datastore = require('nedb');`

This solved the issue. Had to add the `Datastore` variable to my beforeEach function in my unit test as well.

Comment: Your solution is sort of correct but you are not leveraging the type system as intended. The language supports typed, CommonJS and AMD imports. Use `import Datastore = require('nedb');`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added that statement to my imports and when I run my server I get a typescript compiler error: 

**Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from
"mod"', or another module format instead.**

Comment: That means you're circumventing the underlying problem which needs to be resolved in the loader, bundler, or underlying runtime. If you're _outputting_ ES modules then using the syntax is invalid. There is no reason to assume that `require` function exists as it's not part of the es module specification. Furthermore, interop between CmmonJS and ES modules is specified such that, when am ESM imports from a CJS, module.exports is available as and only as a synthetic `default`. TypeScript doesn't do this yet unfortunately, but SystemJS and recent versions of Wepack do provide it.

Comment: so Im basically stuck until they add this support?

Comment: all i want to do is use this one Javascript database. It can't be this complicated to do that in Angular/Typescript. Im not sure what webpack is. I'm just using ng serve to run the app

Comment: TypeScript doesn't implement the hoisting behavior but it does understand it. If you're loader or bundler supports it, set `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in your typescript compiler options and it will work fine with the default import and drop syntax if you using SystemJS or a recent version of Webpack. So the question is are you receiving a runtime error or compiler error?

Comment: if you're using NG serve that means you're using the angular CLI. The angular CLI is terrible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157286/discussion-between-danielbker-and-aluan-haddad).